# How to Convert $matches Array Output from preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php

Using preg_match_all I retrieve (as an example) the follow string:

ABC033-101-143-147-175-142115-

Here is the code for that:

```
if (preg_match_all('#([A-Z]{2}C)((?:[0-9]{3}-){1,10})([0-9]{6})#', $wwalist, $matches))
```

I am able to get the output I want (033-101-143-147-175-) by using the following code:

```
$wwaInfo['locationabbrev'][$wwanum] = $matches[2][$keys[$wwanum]];

echo "locationabbrev";
```

From here, I need to convert the sets of 3 numbers. Every number has a corresponding abbreviation. For example, 033 = FY, 101 = CY, etc. I need locationabbrev to output a string like: "FY-CY-AY-GG-CA" as opposed to the numbers. Any idea how I would go about this?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You can use str_replace but since Tajgeer already have a better answer there is no need for that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) with array of replacements. For example:

```
$locationabbrev = '033-101-143-147-175-'; // example data

// array of replacements
$replacements = [
    '033' => 'FY',
    '101' => 'CY',
    // and so on
];

$translatedabbrev = strtr($locationabbrev, $replacements);

echo $translatedabbrev; // your final string
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One method that uses explode and foreach.
Again, Tajgeers answer is very good. So unless you have some specific reason choose that.
This is just one more way to do it.

```
$repl = [
'033' => 'FY',
'101' => 'CY',
'143' => 'AY',
'147' => 'GG',
'175' => 'CA'   ];

$locationabbrev = '033-101-143-147-175'; 
$arr = explode("-",  $locationabbrev);

Foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val= $repl[$val];
}

$result = implode("-", $arr);
Echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/iolal

Now that I think of it. If you change the regex slightly, you can get the output of the regex as my $arr. Meaning already exploded.
Still the other answer is better. Just a thought.